# Why can't I get any DataGridViewColumn after setting DataGridView.DataSource to a DataTable which has columns?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

**What I need:** when this given Form shows for the first time, it should to create a datatable and bind it to a DataGridView, on which I want the two first columns to be hidden.

Rows will be added to this table by another function, upon user selects an item in other control. User can then set some data using the DataGridView, which should reflect on bound DataTable

I've chosen to use a bound datatable because one of the columns stores data whose type is given from a custom classin my project, and I wanted the other columns to remain strongly typed too.

**The problem**: When it gets to hide the columns, I got "System.NullReferenceException" and then I could verify that DataGridView didn't contain any columns, even if its `DataSource` property was set to a DataTable which has columns, and `AutoGenerateColumns` property was set to true.

What is going wrong? Code below (.NET 4.5, Winforms)

```
Private dtItens as DataTable
Private Sub DataGridViewProcessos_ParentChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
            Handles DataGridViewProcessos.ParentChanged
    If TableViewProcessos.DataSource Is Nothing Then
        dtItens = New DataTable
        dtItens.Columns.Add("pasta_id", GetType(Integer))
        dtItens.Columns.Add("proc_legacy", GetType(LegacyData.Proc))
        dtItens.Columns.Add("numero", GetType(String))
        dtItens.Columns.Add("volumes", GetType(Integer))
        dtItens.Columns.Add("apensamento", GetType(String))
        dtItens.Columns.Add("observacoes", GetType(String))
        DataGridViewProcessos.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        DataGridViewProcessos.DataSource = dtItens
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridViewProcessos_DataSourceChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
            Handles DataGridViewProcessos.DataSourceChanged
    If TableViewProcessos.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
        DataGridViewProcessos.Columns("pasta_id").Visible = False
        DataGridViewProcessos.Columns("proc_legacy").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ParentChanged` event handler does this:

```
If TableViewProcessos.DataSource Is Nothing Then
    '...
    DataGridViewProcessos.DataSource = dtItens
End If
```

and then your `DataSourceChanged` event handler does this:

```
If TableViewProcessos.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
```

You're only setting one `DataSource` if the other is `Nothing` so it's not going to be `Not Nothing` in the other event handler.

Regardless, the `DataSourceChanged` event is raised when you set the `DataSource` property.  The setter of that property performs a number of tasks, one of which is raising that event.  It may well be that the event is raised before the task of creating the columns is performed, which would make it perfectly reasonable that there are no columns to access in the `DataSourceChanged` event handler.  It might make more sense to hide the columns in the code immediately after you actually set the `DataSource`.

Comment: Well, that's what I'd done before. My previous code set the datasource and hid the columns at one straight sequence of statement,  and I  got the same error. The code I posted above was an attempt of mine to solve that. It didn't work, though :-/

Comment: Ah, it's probably because the columns aren't actually named.  Have you actually checked the `Count` of the `Columns` collection?  I think you'll probably find that the columns are there but they aren't simply named after the data source columns by default.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. Property `.Columns.Count` has value of zero at the moment I wanted to hide the first two columns... that are not there. I think I'll figure out another way of accomplish what I need, with DataTable and DataGridView as two separate entities.

Comment: Just to explain my twin testing of `DataSource` whether being `Nothing` in one case and `Not Nothing` in other case: it was just to prevent running my statements upon some early call of those events made by the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it myself doing this:

```
Private dtItens As DataTable
Private Sub DataGridViewProcessos_ParentChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridViewProcessos.ParentChanged
    If DataGridViewProcessos.DataSource Is Nothing Then
        DataGridViewProcessos.Columns.Add(
            New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {
                .DataPropertyName = "pasta_id",
                .Name = "pasta_id",
                .Visible = False})
        DataGridViewProcessos.Columns.Add(
            New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {
                .DataPropertyName = "proc_legacy",
                .Name = "proc_legacy",
                .Visible = False})
        DataGridViewProcessos.Columns.Add(
            New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {
                .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells,
                .DataPropertyName = "numero",
                .HeaderText = "Número",
                .Name = "numero",
                .ReadOnly = True})
        DataGridViewProcessos.Columns.Add(
            New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {
                .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells,
                .DataPropertyName = "volumes",
                .HeaderText = "Volumes",
                .Name = "volumes"})
        DataGridViewProcessos.Columns.Add(
            New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn With {
                .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells,
                .DataPropertyName = "apensamento",
                .DataSource = Apensos,
                .HeaderText = "Apenso a",
                .Name = "apensamento"})
        DataGridViewProcessos.Columns.Add(
            New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {
                .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
                .DataPropertyName = "observacoes",
                .HeaderText = "Observações",
                .Name = "observacoes"})
        DataGridViewProcessos.Columns.Add(
            New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {
                .DataPropertyName = "principal",
                .Name = "principal",
                .Visible = False})
        dtItens = New DataTable
        dtItens.Columns.Add("pasta_id", GetType(Integer))
        dtItens.Columns.Add("proc_legacy", GetType(SicForm.Processo))
        dtItens.Columns.Add("numero", GetType(String))
        dtItens.Columns.Add("volumes", GetType(Integer))
        dtItens.Columns.Add("apensamento", GetType(String))
        dtItens.Columns.Add("observacoes", GetType(String))
        dtItens.Columns.Add("principal", GetType(Boolean))
        DataGridViewProcessos.DataSource = dtItens
    End If
End Sub
```

As it seems, a DataGridView must have this columns previously designed, as it can't be trust to always set its columns automatically according to a DataTable set as its DataSource.

I can't understand why, though, as I can't understand one's itch to -1 this post and never show up to explain why... Sigh. Anyway, I solved my problem and I thank everyone who gave any of his time trying to help. :-)